# Interpreting anti-hacker-alliance analysis

Tags: proxy, packet, internet, browser-hijacking

One of security tools available for web browsing is (http://anti-hacker-alliance.com)
Please find below two readings:

a) Reading for IP 205.x.x.x that state among other-things "you are using proxy server"

b) Reading for my IP 41.x.x.x show 100.0 % loss at the hope before my ip.

Before calling ISP and asking foolish questions sought to check with people who have experience using this tool for possible misconfiguration.  Am connecting one PC directly to the Adsl router.

I have been having issues such those listed at: 
https://superuser.com/questions/831181/mr-google-com-at-email-header

and

https://superuser.com/questions/863502/website-does-not-load

and

https://superuser.com/questions/837243/different-traceroute-endings

And another one where Apple ID was seriously compromised where Apple-specialist consider it unrecoverable due to the fact that it was professionally done.

At some earlier point MS-tunnel was discovered active with ip6 encapsulation via a toll called athtek netwalk.

when used different operating system there has been no answer to: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/466502/different-output-between-network-tool-3-8-1-and-terminal-traceroute

One should suspect a dual configuration at the data-link-layer. Similar to identity theft scenario.

Would someone with experienced knowledge evaluate these results?

Screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC6Hz.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p9uY.jpg).

Comment: Oh my god. The script kiddies who made this must have been really bored.

Comment: Removed that huge image - it doesn't help, and just takes up a vast amount of space. Also, your edit doesn't help the question - what are you asking?

Comment: I was trying to analysis the connection to see if there is a bottleneck, what makes Network tool constantly idle, and/or why mail does not arrive, etc. Basically troubleshooting. In addition to evaluating one of few automated internet security tools as each tool might have slightly different approach. i.e. one may use tcp packet instead of udp in trace-rout. While sharing results can be beneficiary since each contributor has different connection. My ultimate goal is to spot up-normality, if any.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a lame site doing basic checks (ping, traceroute, whois, geo IP lookup) on some IP you entered in the search form and presents all of that in a scary looking webpage, I definitely wouldn't call that a "security tool", it's more of a toy for script kiddies.

They for some reason assume that you're using a proxy, they can either guess that based on the presence of a `Forwarded` or `X-Forwarded-For` header or just because your IP is in some outdated open proxy database - you probably have a dynamic IP and happened to be allocated the IP of someone else who deliberately ran an open proxy or got compromised.

Just forget that horror, here are some (real) tools if you are worried about the security of your computer :

- http://icanhazip.com/ - to get the real IP of the host requesting the page (this will be the proxy's IP if you're using one)
- http://nmap.org/ - port scanner, run this from a remote host and point it at your IP to scan all open ports on your computer
- http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx - open mail relay test, to see if a badly configured mail server is running on your computer and can be abused to send spam
- http://www.webmastify.com/resources/proxy/ - open HTTP proxy test, I've not used it myself so I don't know if it's reliable, I prefer to test manually using telnet

Comment: webmastify Open Proxy Detector:                           IP Address: 41.69.153.180
Hostname: Unresolvable
 
Checking Port 80. . .  Port Closed
Checking Port 2301. . .  Port Closed
Checking Port 3128. . .  Port Closed
Checking Port 6588. . .  Port Closed
Checking Port 8000. . .  Port Closed
Checking Port 8080. . .  Port Closed

Comment: @user176105 all common proxy ports are closed. You may try a full scan using nmap if you're really paranoid.